# Ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException в principal.getName()

Tags: java, spring, исключения, spring-mvc, spring-security

Привет всем!
Прошу помочь с вопросом. Я начинающий Java Dev и многому еще хочу научится.

Логинится пользователь успешно ( занесен в базу данных)
после чего хочу ему привязать таск, но при сохранении Ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException в principal.getName().
Когда без пользователя заношу в БД информацию о таске то ошибок нет.

**Код:
**
**файл web.xml**

`

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

     <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>



</web-app>
```

`

**в файле servlet-context.xml**

`

```
 <import resource="appContext.xml"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20000000"/>
    </bean>


    <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator"/>
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>


<!--    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="file:${catalina.home}/resources/"/> -->

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

</beans>`
```

**security.xml**

```
 <import resource="appContext.xml"/>

    <security:http>
        <security:form-login login-page="/index" login-processing-url="/loginproc" authentication-success-forward-url="/profile"/>

        <security:intercept-url pattern="admin" method="GET" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll()"/>

        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

**appContext.xml**

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="primary"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="ua.taskm.*"/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="ua.taskm.repository"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

 <bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"></bean>

</beans>`
```

**класс TaskServiceImpl**

```
 @Service
    public class TaskServiceImpl implements TaskService {

        @Autowired
        private TaskRepository taskRepository;

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        public void save(Task task) {
            taskRepository.save(task);

        }

        public List<Task> findAll() {

            return taskRepository.findAll();
        }

        public Task findOne(int id) {

            return taskRepository.findOne(id);
        }

        public void delete(int id) {
            taskRepository.delete(id);

        }

        public List<Task> allFetch() {

            return taskRepository.findAllByFetch();
        }

        public void saveTaskImage(MultipartFile multipartFile, String taskId) {

            Task task = taskRepository.findOne(Integer.parseInt(taskId));

            String path = System.getProperty("catalina.home") + "/resources/" + task.getId() + "/"
                    + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();

            task.setTaskPathImage("resources/" + task.getId() + "/" + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());

            File file = new File(path);

            try {
                file.mkdirs();

                try {
                    FileUtils.cleanDirectory(
                            new File(System.getProperty("catalina.home") + "/resources/" + task.getId() + "/"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    FileUtils.cleanDirectory(
                            new File(System.getProperty("catalina.home") + "/resources/" + task.getId() + "/"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                multipartFile.transferTo(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("error with file");
            }
            taskRepository.save(task);

        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public void addTask(Principal principal,String description, String date) {

            User user = userRepository.findfetchUser(Integer.parseInt(principal.getName()));    **// ошибка (   java.lang.NullPointerException)**    


            Task task = new Task(description, date);
            user.getTasks().add(task);
            userRepository.save(user);

        }

        @Override
        public void saveTaskImage(Principal principal, MultipartFile multipartFile, String id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
```

**TaskController**

```
@Controller
public class TaskController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addtaskpage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addTaskPage() {

        return "addtask";

    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/addtask", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String adddTask(Principal principal, @RequestParam String description, @RequestParam String date) {
        taskService.addTask(principal, description, date);   

        return "redirect:/profile";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String delTask(@PathVariable String id) {
        taskService.delete(Integer.parseInt(id));
        return "redirect:/profile";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editTask(@PathVariable String id) {

        return "edit";
    }

}
```

ниже Log с исключением:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with
>   path [/taskm] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   ua.taskm.serviceImpl.TaskServiceImpl.addTask(TaskServiceImpl.java:95)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.addTask(Unknown Source)   at
>   ua.taskm.controller.TaskController.adddTask(TaskController.java:45)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

**класс User**

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    private String pathImage;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "task_user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_task"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_user"))
    private List<Task> tasks;

    @Enumerated
    private Role role;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String name, String username, String email, String password) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getOriginUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return String.valueOf(id);
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPathImage() {
        return pathImage;
    }

    public void setPathImage(String pathImage) {
        this.pathImage = pathImage;
    }

    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
        return authorities;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {

        return true;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {

        return true;
    }

    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {

        return true;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {

        return true;
    }

}
```

**UserRepository**

`

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    User findByUsername(String username);

    User findByEmail(String email);

    @Query(value = "select u from User u left join fetch u.tasks t where u.id =:id")
    User findfetchUser(@Param("id") int id);

}
```

`

Прошу помочь разобраться и найти мою ошибку.
Прошу прощения за не очень качественный код.

Comment: Ваш `principal` равен `null`. Проверьте то место, где Вы вызываете Ваш `POST` запрос `adddTask` на клиенте. Соответствует ли имя параметра в отсылаемом запросе с именем получаемого параметра.

Comment: @ Вот как выглядит что получаем от пользователя   <sf:form action="addtask"  method="post">
  <input class="inp" name="description" placeholder="Enter task"/>
  <input name="date" class="date" type="date">
<button>Add</button>
  
  </sf:form> . На сколько я понимаю после LogIn principal сам должен брать того пользователя который залогинился. Но я могу ошибаться

Comment: Я про формирование объекта User перед передачей. Где оно?

Comment: @VladimirParfenov я наверное что то упустил. Вот достаю юзера с базы  User user = userRepository.findfetchUser(Integer.parseInt(principal.getName()));    на UserService есть поиск @Query(value = "select u from User u left join fetch u.tasks t where u.id =:id")
 User findfetchUser(@Param("id") int id);   но я этом не уверен..

Answer (score 0):

Юзера нужно дергать из `Security`, но никак не добавлением в конструктор класса `Principal`, который создается пустым, т.е. 
'SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()'

Comment: @Artem может есть идеи как это реализовать? а то я не знаю(

Comment: @VBezverhnyy я не особо в этом разбираюсь, сорри